# Advice on how to tackle this lisp function.

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, clisp

I have written a function called `my_rotate` that takes a number from a user and creates a list up to five numbers. `my_rotate` then, pops off the first element of the list and adds it to the end of the list. Any advice on how I could write `my_rotate` to take in another number `n` and rotate the list based on the number `n`, in which the user entered.

Example:

`> (my_rotate 1 2)`

Outputs:

`(3 4 5 1 2)`

This is what I have so far:

```
(defun my_rotate (y)
    (append (loop for i from (+ 1 y) to (+ 4 y) collect i)
    (list y)))
```

Comment: What's this for anyway?  There may be better ways to accomplish your overall goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the function.
I create two lists and then concatenate them.

```
(defun my-rotate (length shift)
  "Return a list of given LENGTH, rotated by SHIFT."
  (nconc
   (loop for i from (1+ shift) to (- length shift -2) collect i)
   (loop for i from 1 to shift collect i)))
(my-rotate 7 2)
==> (3 4 5 6 7 1 2)
```

Note that since both [`loop`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/06_a.htm)s produce [*fresh*](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/26_glo_f.htm#fresh) lists, I use [`nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm) instead of [`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm).

If, however, you want to rotate an existing list, you will need to do something else:

```
(defun rotate-list (list shift)
  "Rotate the given LIST by the specified SHIFT."
  (let ((len (length list)))
    (setq shift (mod shift len)) ; handle circular shifts
    (append (nthcdr (- len shift) list)
            (butlast list shift))))
(rotate-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 2)
==> (5 6 1 2 3 4)
(rotate-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 20)
==> (5 6 1 2 3 4)               ; same because 20 = 2 mod 6
(rotate-list '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 0)
==> (1 2 3 4 5 6)               ; unchanged
```

Note that [`nthcdr`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nthcdr.htm) points inside the original list, so we have to use `append` to avoid modifying the argument.

Note also that we scan the `list` argument *twice* (once in `nthcdr` and once in [`butlast`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_butlas.htm)).
If your lists are huge, and profiling shows that this function is the bottleneck, you might want to re-write this using a loop (this is scenario is so unlikely, that I already regret having wasted my time writing this note).

Comment: Thank you, I am a little confused on where in this function the list is being actually shifted. Could you clarify?

Comment: Which function? 1st or 2nd? In both cases I split the original list at the right spot and then merge the parts. IOW, this is functionally equivalent to shift, but is done in a single go.

Comment: I'm sorry, I got confused on my implementation of the function to make me think something was wrong. I do see which loop is doing what. Could you break down what each loop is doing in the first function, so that I can understand what each loop is doing entirely.

Comment: my two loops are basically the same as yours. if you want an explanation of how `loop` works, please ask a separate question. SO policy is against "question scope creep" - let us keep focused on rotation here.

Comment: thank you for your help. I now have a better understanding on how to go about rotating list.